# Please help how to solve this

Tags: flutter, intl, pubspec.yaml

This is the message, when I try to run flutter pub get.

> Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.1 and local_delivery_admin depends on intl ^0.17.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is forbidden.

Down is my pubspec.ymal

```
name: local_delivery_admin
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5

  # BASE
  intl: ^0.17.0
  html: ^0.15.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1

  # CONNECTIVITY
  http: ^0.13.5
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2

  # STATE MANAGEMENT
  mobx: ^2.1.3
  flutter_mobx: ^2.0.6+5

  # TOAST
  fluttertoast: ^8.1.1

  # IMAGE
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.6

  # UI
  lottie: ^2.0.0
  fl_chart: ^0.55.2
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^20.3.58
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.2

  # COUNTRY
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2

  # PACKAGE INFO
  #package_info_plus: ^3.0.2

  # LUNCH URL
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7

  # FIREBASE
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  firebase_messaging: ^13.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
  cloud_firestore: ^3.5.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.8.13
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.11
  firebase_database: ^9.1.7
  paginate_firestore: ^1.0.3+1

  # TIMELINE
  timeline_tile: ^2.0.0

  # DATE TIME PICKER
  date_time_picker: ^2.1.0

  elegant_notification: ^1.6.4

  # CURRENCY PICKER
  currency_picker: ^2.0.12

  # READ MORE LESS
  readmore: ^2.2.0

  # GOOGLE MAP
  maps_launcher: ^2.0.1

  # DOWNLOAD INVOICE PDF
  pdf: ^3.8.3
  printing: ^5.9.3

  universal_html: ^2.0.8

  #COMMON
  flutter_vector_icons: ^2.0.0

  #UI
  responsive_grid_list: ^1.3.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0

  #OTHER
  file_picker: ^4.5.1

  url_strategy: ^0.2.0

  # DOWNLOAD INVOICE PDF
  path_provider: ^2.0.11

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^2.3.2
  mobx_codegen: ^2.1.1
  #flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/flag/
    - assets/partener/
```

I'm trying to build a flutter app

Comment: See how version constraints work in pubspec: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning#semantic-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the intl library

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: any
```